# What is summation of $\log n + \log \frac{n}{2} + \log\frac{n}{4} + \dotsb + \text{last term}?$

Tags: calculus, summation

What is the summation of the mathematical series

$$\log n + \log \frac{n}{2} + \log\frac{n}{4} + \dotsb + \text{last term}?$$

and what is it called please? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know any identities for expanding $\log(a/b)$? And is this a finite sum or an infinite one?

Comment: last term would be log(n/2^k) so I believe it is finite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the sum is finite and using $\log(a)+\log(b) = \log(ab)$, we get

$$\log(n)+\log(n/2)+\cdots+\log(n/2^k)  = \log \left( \prod _{j=0}^k \frac{n}{2^j} \right) = \log \left( \frac{n^{k+1}}{2^{1+2+\cdots +k}} \right).$$

Now use $$\sum_{j=1}^k j = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$ to add up the powers of $2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{\ell = 0 }^N\log(n/2^{\ell})&=\sum_{\ell = 0 }^N(\log(n)-\ell \log(2))\\\\
&=(N+1)\log(n)-\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\log(2)
\end{align}$$